Observation without interaction thought experiment
Here I am going to talk about a thought experiment that I have thought
There is some isolated place in the universe where there is no EM field other than the field created by a moving point charge which we know is not accelerating as there is no other EM field . Then 2 observers (stationary wrt each other) are placed at 2 different places and they monitor the direction of the electric field.
For uniformly moving charge we know it always points towards the charge. For 2 observers we get 2 different directions and where the directions intersect will be the charge present. At the next instance, the point of intersection will change. Measurement at a place can affect the charge after a certain time interval. This time interval is the time taken by light to travel from that point to the charge. We will thus take data of the directions for extremely short interval of time so that we don't get data after the charge is disturbed by observation.
Once we know the time interval and change in point of intersection, we will get the velocity of the charge wrt those observers. So we have determined everything accurately.  It is a contradiction to uncertainty principle. So what is going wrong or where am I wrong and have such experiment already been done?

When talking of "point charge" you enter the realm where quantum mechanics has to be used,  The uncertainty principle is  in th  QM  realm. Any observation by observers requires multiple QM interactions and considering that any QM predictions are on probabilities of the interaction happening, you are wrong in your assumptions.

Heisenberg's uncertainty principle applies also to the photon field that $\vec E,\vec B$ come from, and implies that you cannot make an infinitely precise measurement of the electric field without losing information about how it is changing with respect to time.
So, in practice, your measurement of this distant particle has errors due to the measurement of the fields, and this is going to be several times larger than the Heisenberg uncertainty because it's far away from the detectors and little uncertainties in the directions of the field create big uncertainties in the calculated position.

So the whole concept of uncertainty arrise from the law that E and B come from quantised photon field which is quantised . That means classical electrodynamics will not predict such kind of uncertainty but QED will. This means all the formulla for fields and potentials in classical ED are wrong?

@Physics there is consistency in the mainstream physics theories. The classical theory can be shown that it emerges from the quantum level, that is the way the theory was decided, for continuity in the different regimes.
